# ASP.NET Core Environment Variable Not Set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use Environment variables in my application so I don't have to bother maintaining config files across different systems.  Maybe I just have a misunderstanding about where these variables are coming from.

First, I created a Windows System variable called `MediatrExampleDbConnection` on my local **System** -> **Advanced** properties

Then, I have this code in my **Startup.cs** :

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

When I try to access it later, it comes back **null** :

```
var MediatrConnectionString = Configuration["MediatrExampleDbConnection"];
```

Isn't this supposed to pull from my local System variables since I have `.AddEnvironmentVariables();` in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my misunderstanding.

According to this post: [Accessing environment variables from ASP.NET Core 1 RC1 IConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994077/accessing-environment-variables-from-asp-net-core-1-rc1-iconfiguration)

These are Web Application, Environment Variables from your Project properties: 
[image: Project properties]

> These are **NOT** coming from your Windows System Environment Variables in
>   Advanced System Settings.